# Reading JSON response in OnCreatingTicket without using MapJsonKey (claims)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, aspnet-contrib

I am trying to read the actual JSON response from Google API after successful OAuth authentication flow. I have read the MS Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-5.0#establish-the-authentication-scope) where they use options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey to map each key to a Claim. However I do not want to add claims, I just want to read all of the JSON keys and values returned.

```
.AddGoogle(options => {
    options.ClientId = _conf["MyClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = _conf["MySecret"];

    options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = ctx => {
// How do I read the JSON returned, via ctx object? I have tried ctx.Response.Body, but didn't get much further.

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
```

Comment: The context will/should include the JSON payload as part of the `OAuthCreatingTicketContext` that you can inspect. You can see how a similar thing is achieved in some OAuth 2.0 libraries I help maintain: https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/blob/5ea246e503468862fa2eb02e2d0fed05702fc77d/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Amazon/AmazonAuthenticationHandler.cs#L72-L79

Comment: So I need to instantiate a new OAuthCreatingTicketContext? Or can it be accessed already?

Comment: No, it is already available on the `OAuthCreatingTicketContext` you are given as an argument to your `OnCreatingTicket` handler: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.oauth.oauthcreatingticketcontext.user?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_OAuth_OAuthCreatingTicketContext_User

Comment: Thank you, Martin! You pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking the *Context.Response* for the JSON payload, one has to access the *Context.TokenResponse*, the "response from an provider for an OAuth token request":

```
options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = ctx => {
    var payload = ctx.TokenResponse.Response;
    // Do something with the payload, deserialize or whatever, now you can access all JSON key/value pairs such as "profile_picture" or "some_key"
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.oauth.oauthtokenresponse?view=aspnetcore-2.0.